# How is the flow of build when I execute an async function with setState inside initState?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to understand the flow of build when I execute an async function with setState inside initState. For example:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    asyncMethod();
    super.initState();
  }

asyncMethod() async {
  some async call here
  setState(){}
}
```

I first thought that initState procs build, then setState from asyncMethod procs build again or vice versa (which cames first). But on my tests, build is getting called just once. How does this work?

I am just curious about the criteria of calling build on this situation.

Comment: `initState` cant be async method, calling `asyncMethod()` doesn't pause execution/ don't wait to be finished.  futureMethod only wait when you'll use `await` before it.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, I know that, but I was wondering, the build method is called just once on this example, but it was not meant to be called twice? One after initState and one for async setState()?

Comment: once you call setState, build method will call, 1 for first frame, 2nd for setState calling

Comment: have you `await` "some async call here"?

Comment: @psking await keyword can be used just on async methods, initState can't be async

Comment: you have `asyncMethod() async { ...` so you can call `await` inside it, my question is if you called `await` before calling `setState`?

Comment: Oh, I see, but the problem here is that initState will continue the flow besides asyncMethod awaiting for some data. So my doubt was that with that setState inside that async call, it will trigger 2 builds(1 for initState and 1 for setState)? Cause on my tests build is being called just once (or if the async is long enough, build gets called, then after the async call is called again)

Comment: "But on my tests, build is getting called just once. How does this work?" because you did not `await` for any `Future`, once you do it, you will see two rebuilds

Comment: @pskink I see, so if I await, it will proc initState build, then the setState build, right?

Comment: add `print('some log label')` inside `initState` and `build` methods and check the logs

Answer (score 0):

The provided callback is immediately called synchronously. It must not return a future (the callback cannot be async), since then it would be unclear when the state was actually being set.

The above line is from Flutter doc of setState callback.

Comment: Sorry, I put "some async call" inside setState but I meant to put inside the asyncMethod right before setState()

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an error if you call await in initState to setState. The error will be something as "Set state called during build".

However it's possible to add a "PostFrameCallback" that will be executed after the first build. You can use await as normally in the _asyncMethod();

```
@override
void initState () {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
    _asyncMethod();
  });    
}
```